# Printing a java list

Tags: java, list, printing

So i have a little problem here, im trying to print a list from right to left and from left to right, this code works fine printing from right to left but from left to right no, any help please?

My code:

```
package listas;

import java.util.Scanner;


class nodo {

    int info;

    nodo ligader;
    nodo ligaizq;
}

class Listas {

    static nodo F = null;
    static nodo Q = null;
    static nodo P = null;
    static nodo x = null;
    static nodo T = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = 0;

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Menu");
                System.out.println("1.  Crea Inicio");             
                System.out.println("2. Insertar antes de referencia ");
                System.out.println("3.  Mostrar");
                System.out.println("4. Salir");
                System.out.println("Opcion:");
                m = Integer.valueOf(y.next());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.print("");
            }

            try {
                switch (m) {
                    case 1:
                        creaininodo();
                        System.out.println("Termina Programa que Crea Inicio de Lista");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        InsertarAntes();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Mostrar();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("La opcion que escogio no se encuentra,favor de escoger otra.");
                        break;

                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Datos introducidos erroneos.");
            }
        } while (m != 4);
    }

    public static void creaininodo() {

        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opc = 1;
        int dato;
        if (P == null) {
            P = new nodo();
            System.out.println("Dame Dato: ");
            dato = Integer.valueOf(y.next());
            P.info = dato;
            P.ligaizq = null;
            P.ligader = null;
            F = P;
        }

        do {
            Q = new nodo();
            System.out.println("Dame Dato: ");
            dato = Integer.valueOf(y.next());
            Q.info = dato;
            Q.ligader = P;
            Q.ligaizq = null;
            P = Q;

            System.out.println("Otro nodo 1(SI) 2 (NO)");
            opc = Integer.valueOf(y.next());
        } while (opc != 2);

    }

    public static void InsertarAntes() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ref;
        int dato;
        System.out.println("Inserte un valor de referencia: ");
        ref = Integer.valueOf(sc.next());
        Q = P;
        boolean band = false;

        while ((Q.info != ref) && (band == false)) {
            if (Q.ligader != null) {
               T=Q;
                Q = Q.ligader;

            } else {
                band = true;
            }
        }

        if (band == true) {
            System.out.println("El elemento no fue enconntrado");
        } else {
            x = new nodo();
            System.out.println("Inserte el nuevo valor: ");
            dato = sc.nextInt();
            x.info = dato;
            x.ligader = Q;
            T.ligader=x;
            Q.ligaizq = x;
            x.ligaizq = T;
            if (P == Q) {
                P = x;
            }
        }

    }



    public static void Mostrar() {

        System.out.println("La Lista Creada es: ");
        System.out.println("Campo Informacion de derecha a izquierda:");
        for (nodo i = P; i != null; i = i.ligader) {
            System.out.print(" -" + i.info + "- ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Campo Informacion de izquierda a derecha:");
        for (nodo i = F; i != null; i = i.ligader) {
            System.out.print(" -" + i.info + "- ");

        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Basically this program works by giving some numbers to the list in case 1 and 2 (in case 2 you just chose a reference number you previously add in case 2 so you insert the number in the list before the reference number) and in case 3 is the problem the code prints from right to left but no from left to right.

For example, we choose case 1 and we add 3 numbers 3,6 and 5 after that we choose case 3 and prints:

La Lista Creada es: 
Campo Informacion de derecha a izquierda: (right to left (fine))
 -3-  -6-  -5-
Campo Informacion de izquierda a derecha: (left to right just one number)
 -5-

Sorry for my bad english, I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not entirely sure what *ligader* and *ligaizq* means. But assuming you want to implement a doubly linked list I'd expect them to indicate the *previous* and *next* node in the list.

You'll want to change the following in your input method `creaininodo()`:

```
    Q.info = dato;
    Q.ligader = P;
    P.ligaizq = Q; // instead of Q.ligaizq = null;
```

And then modify your output method for left to right to actually use the link to the previous node for traversal:

```
    for (nodo i = F; i != null; i = i.ligaizq) { // using i.ligaizq!
        System.out.print(" -" + i.info + "- ");
    }
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as accepted in order to close the question.